# Java substring new to learning

Tags: java, substring

Im new to java and understand substring pretty well. Im confused to what the str.substring(i,i +3) means. the i is the index of what? (0,0+3) ? thank you.

here is my code

public class xyzThere {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(work("abcxyz"));
    System.out.println(work("abc.xyz")) ;   
    System.out.println(work("xyz.abc"));
}
       static public boolean work(String str) {
        
          
           
           if (str.length() >= 3 && str.substring(0,3).equals("xyz"))
               return true;
           for (int i=0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
               if ( str.substring(i,i +3).equals("xyz") && str.charAt(i -1) != '.'  )
                 
                   return true;
               }
           
           
          return false;

       }   }
```

Comment: `i` is the counter variable of your for loop and its value will change with each iteration. [Perhaps looking up what a for-loop does might help you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: 'i' is just a numeric value of type integer.

Comment: the first argument of substring is the start index and the second argument is the end index. Notice that the end index is exclusive and the start index is inclusive

Comment: Side notes: instead of `str.length() >= 3 && str.substring(0,3).equals("xyz")` you can simply use `str.startsWith("xyz")`. And instead of `str.substring(i,i +3).equals("xyz")` you can use `str.regionMatches(i, "xyz", 0 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

For example. In the following string we have 6 characters. So if you call .length() on the string it will return 6. Note that its indices will range from 0 to 5 (not to 6).

> "A tree"

The indices would be like the following:

```
0 -> 'A'
1 -> ' '
2 -> 't'
3 -> 'r'
4 -> 'e'
5 -> 'e'
```

Using substring you can get a part of this string.
Your result will be starting at the specifed begin index and will end at the specified end index.

### Important:

The start index is inclusive, while the end index is exclusive.

Which means that if we use substring from 2 to 4, we won't get "tre". We will get "tr", since the end index is not included.

---

Programmers often use excluded end indices, since it is easier to work with them.
For example. Imagine our string "A tree" is called s like this:

```
String s = "A tree";
```

if you would want everything starting at index 2 you could do:

```
String result = s.substring(2, s.length()); // Result would also be 'tree' for this example
```

If the end index wouldn't be exclusive you would need to write:

```
String result = s.substring(2, s.length() - 1); // This is an example that would return "tree", IF and only if end indices wouldn't be excluded
```

That is why programmers often exclude the end index.

Of corse if you want to start at a certain index and want to go till the end you don't need to use

```
String result = s.substring(2, s.length()); // Result would also be 'tree' for this example
```

but instead you could use the alternative version of substring, where you only provide a begin index and not an end index. Like this:

```
String result = s.substring(2); // Result would also be 'tree' for this example
```

---

Please take a look at the documentation for

1. substring(int, int) -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-
2. substring(int) -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "abcxyz";
```

The substring is on a loop so at the first pass `text` will be equal to :

```
System.out.println(text.substring(0, 0 + 3)); // abc
```

At the second pass :

```
System.out.println(text.substring(1, 1 + 3)); // bcx
```

Etc.